# How to remove quotes from the string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I replace '5,6' into 5,6 in sql or '5' into 5. Because when I write a sql to:

```
SELECT  ID,RuleStatus as Name FROM RulesStatus where ID in ('5,6')
```

I do not get any results.I am getting this value as parameter from the application.

Comment: your application should use parameterized queries. for safety, your application needs updated.

Comment: Is ID defined as string or int? If int, then you don't want any quotes around the value.

Comment: Its defined as string

Comment: Then it should be `('5', '6')`. You should find a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: The values is coming from application as '5,6' that's why i was trying to convert it to 5,6 or '5','6'

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  `'5,6'` is a string, whereas `(5, 6)` is a list of values.  The two are not the same.

How can you deal with this?  Here are some possibilities:

- Use `string_split()` or a related function to break this into values:  `where RulesStatus in (select * from string_slit('5,6', ','))`
- Use XML parsing to the same effect.
- Use a recursive CTE to split apart the string.
- Use string logic:  `where ',' + '5,6' + ',' like '%,' + cast(RuleStatus as varchar(255)) + ',%')`
- Use dynamic SQL
- Use a temporary table/table variable to store the list of values

Comment: Which one do you recommend?